# Gazebo on headless simulation server

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

is there possibility to run Gazebo on headless server? I would like to setup complete ROS development server including Gazebo. The machine has graphic card with no OpenGL support. There is MESA so, for instance it's possible to run glxgears remotely (ssh -X). But Gazebo crashes with ([RViZ also crashes](http://answers.ros.org/question/125861/running-rviz-through-x-forwarding-on-headless-machine/)):

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadDrawable
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  5 (X_GLXMakeCurrent)
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  31
```

It's possible to run gzserver like this:

```
user@server:~$ xvfb-run gzserver
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.9.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:12002
Msg Publicized address: xyz
Error [RenderEngine.cc:641] Unable to create glx visual
Warning [RenderEngine.cc:92] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled
```

...but it would require installation of ROS/Gazebo also on client's machine which I would like to avoid and moreover it disables rendering (I can't use DepthCameraSensor). Any experience / tips will be highly appreciated :-)

UPDATE:

On server, I installed libgl1-mesa-swx11 (instead of libgl1-mesa-dri) and now it works somehow - it's possible to run gzserver on server or gazebo through X tunneling (this is painfully slow). Using webclient is probably a way to go.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5387/gazebo-on-headless-simulation-server/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think you can try to use the web client.
In this way you could connect to the server in your browser without a gazebo installation on client side.

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Gzweb

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on 2014-02-04**:
Thanks for hint. I didn't know there something like this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe that this has appeared in the past several times. Let me provide several references, hopefully they can help you:

- http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2153/drcsim-cant-figure-out-how-to-run-gazebo-on-remote/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/9324/run-gazebo-remotely/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/35013/running-gazebo-headless-in-fuerte-over-ssh

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on 2014-02-10**:
Many thanks, I will check those links.